# How to calculate date range for week and month in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, range

Can someone guide me on date range in JavaScript?

I want to calculate one week and month date range from today's date; I.e, if today is "18th july 2010", the range for the week should be "11/07/2010 - 8/07/2010"
and for the month it should be "01/07/2010 - 18/07/2010".

Thanks for your guidance in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var now = new Date();
var nextWeek = new Date(new Date(now).setDate(now.getDate() + 7));
var nextMonth = new Date(new Date(now).setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's reliable to add dates like that if say today's date was 25th. It might work on some browsers, but might on others.

Comment: The Date.prototype.set* functions overflow safely like this according to spec and in all implementations I've ever seen. For example `setDate` from ECMA-262 v.3 (15.9.5.36, p.128) essentially says turn the number of days into a number of seconds and adjust the original date by that number of seconds... so if there are more days than there are in the current month, the month will roll over...

Comment: thanks @no, I'd wrongly assumed that overflow will not be handled properly on each browser, and always resorted to manual timestamp conversions, so this is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you looking at the excellent [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library which has many useful functions to manipulate dates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is vanilla JS function that will take a date (or blank) as input and return an object with start and end date of that week (assuming Monday is first day of week :) )

```
function rangeWeek (dateStr) {
    if (!dateStr) dateStr = new Date().getTime();
    var dt = new Date(dateStr);
    dt = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
    dt = new Date(dt.getTime() - (dt.getDay() > 0 ? (dt.getDay() - 1) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 : 6 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return { start: dt, end: new Date(dt.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 - 1) };
}

console.log(rangeWeek());
console.log(rangeWeek('2013/9/1'));
```

You can change accordingly for Sunday-Saturday.

Comment: I know this post is old :) But thanks for helping me, out. This worked perfectly and as expected. I'm pretty glad that i didn't have to come up with that myself.

Comment: how can i loop this to get week from now until the end of the month?