# Convert Date range into Week range using moment js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have date ranges called from and to.
I want to convert it to weeks in the range of Sunday to Saturday.
Eg we have a range of `01-10-2014 - 31-10-2014`

Then week data should be :

```
01-10-2014 - 04-10-2014
05-102014  - 11-10-2014
12-10-2014 - 18-10-2014 
19-10-2014 - 25-10-2014
26-10-2014 - 31-10-2014
```

How can this be achieved using `moment.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has a similar answer here, you can refer here:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884615/12772355

Answer (score 0):

Use `.diff()` method of moment.

```js
const ranges = [
  { from: '01-10-2014', to: '04-10-2014' },
  { from: '05-10-2014', to: '11-10-2014' },
  { from: '12-10-2014', to: '18-10-2014' },
  { from: '19-10-2014', to: '25-10-2014' },
  { from: '26-10-2014', to: '31-10-2014' },
  { from: '01-10-2014', to: '31-10-2014' },
  { from: '09-10-2014', to: '31-10-2014' }
];

for (const range of ranges) {
  const dateFormat = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
  const diff = Math.abs(moment(range.from, dateFormat).diff(moment(range.to, dateFormat), 'weeks', true));
  console.log(diff.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't need a floating number like result, remove the `true` like thirt parameter of `.diff()` and the `.toFixed(2)`.